# Moments of random variable $X$ with PDF $f_X(x)=c\cdot(1 - x^2)$ on $(0,1)$, and PDF of $X^2$

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable defined on the interval $[0,1]$ with density function $f_X(u)=c(1−u^2)$ for some suitable constant $c$.
>   Find: **(a)** the value of $c$, **(b)** **(i)** the expectation and **(ii)** the variance of $X$. Also find **(c)** the density function of the random variable $Y = X^{2}$.

Now I've already attempted **(a)** by integrating $(1-u^{2})$ between $0$ and $1$ (like $\pi$ in the Cauchy density function) and got $c=\frac{2}{3}$ and also for **(b) (i)** I integrated $uc(1-u^{2})$ between $0$ and $1$ which came out to be $c/4 = 1/6$.

Have I done these first $2$ parts correctly? If so how do I go about doing the rest and if not same question but also where did I go wrong?

Comment: First problem: the integral of $\frac23(1-u^2)$ on $(0,1)$ is... not $1$.

Comment: @Did You're right it isn't but I never integrated that anyway. it's actually the integral of cu(1-u^2) = 2/3u(1-u^2) on [0,1] which gives 1/6 as I've written already.

Comment: To be clear, at present your solution to (a) is wrong. So, what is the value of $c$ you are getting?

Comment: Replacing $f_X(x)$ by $f_X(u)$ in the title, as you just did, was ill-advised. Please *think*.

Comment: @Did To find c I integrated (1-u^2) on (0,1) and got c=2/3.

Comment: Sooo... if a PDF is $f(x)=cg(x)$, you think that $c$ is the integral of $g$? Something should strike you as odd here...

Comment: @Did Lol that does look quite odd now that you've pointed it out. So how would you suggest I go about finding c?

Comment: Maybe come back to the definitions... In the context of my comment, $f$ must integrate to $1$ hence $cg$ must integrate to $1$ hence $$\int cg=c\cdot\int g=1$$ hence $$c=\ldots$$

Comment: @Did Ohhhhh so you're saying that c = 1/(∫g) so in this particular question, c is 1 divided by the integral of (1-u^2) on (0,1). Is that right?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did I see, thank you.

Comment: @Did Okay, I did as you hinted and got c=3/2, E(X)=1/4 & E(X^2)=1/8 so Var(X)=1/16. How can I go about finding the density function for Y=X^2? Do I go about finding the density function for Y?

Comment: For (c), do a [change of variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables) with $g(x) = x^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(a)** $\int_{0}^{1}f_X(u) = 1 $ therefore $\int_{0}^{1}c\cdot(1-u^2)=1$

so $c=\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{1}1-u^2\space du}$

$\int_{0}^{1}1-u^\space du=\frac{2}{3}$, therefore $c=\frac{3}{2}$

**(b)**
**(i)** $E(X)=\int_{0}^{1}u\cdot f_X(u)\space du=\frac{3}{2}\cdot \int_{0}^{1}u\cdot (1-u^2) \space du= \frac{3}{8}$

**(ii)** $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2,$

$E(X^2)=\int_{0}^{1}u^2\cdot f_X(u)\space du=\frac{3}{2}\int_{0}^{1}u\cdot(1-u^2)\space du=\frac{1}{5}$

$Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2=\frac{1}{5}-\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^2=\frac{19}{320}$

**(c)**
$f_Y(u) = \frac{d}{du}\left(F_Y(u)\right)$

$F_Y(u)=P(Y≤u)=P(X^2≤ u)=P(-\sqrt{u}≤X≤\sqrt{u})=\frac{3}{2}\int_{-\sqrt{u}}^{\sqrt{u}}f_X(u)\space du=\frac{3}{2}\int_{-\sqrt{u}}^{\sqrt{u}}1-u^2\space du=3u^{\frac{1}{2}}-u^{\frac{3}{2}}=F_Y(u)$

$\therefore f_Y(u)=\frac{d}{du}\left(3u^{\frac{1}{2}}-u^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)=\frac{3-3u}{2\sqrt{u}}$